# How can i use case alias in a select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, mariadb

In SQL how may I use case alias in a select query the one in question is a count, for example you will see below the select alias is set with `as` but i can not use the alias in the rest of the select query. Using MySQL.

The line in question below is:
`(win / total) * 100 as win_percent`

```
    DECLARE @team TEXT;
    SET @team = "myTeam";
    SELECT 
        @team team,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN home = @team then 1 ELSE NULL END) as home,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN away = @team then 1 ELSE NULL END) as away,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN (away = @team or home = @team) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as total,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN winner = @team and (home = @team or away = @team)  then 1 ELSE NULL END) as win,    
        COUNT(CASE WHEN (home = @team or away = @team) and (winner <> @team and winner <> "0") then 1 ELSE NULL END) as lost,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN winner = "0" and (home = @team or away = @team) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as tie,
        (869 / 1928) * 100 as win_percent,
        (win / total) * 100 as win_percent
    from matches;
```

Comment: Noway. Use expressions instead of aliases. Or move  your query into subquery/CTE and use win / total column values in outer query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a subquery and have that final win_percent in the outermost query. The query should look like this:

```
SELECT a.*,
    (win / total) * 100 as win_percent
FROM (
SELECT 
        @team team,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN home = @team then 1 ELSE NULL END) as home,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN away = @team then 1 ELSE NULL END) as away,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN (away = @team or home = @team) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as total,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN winner = @team and (home = @team or away = @team)  then 1 ELSE NULL END) as win,    
        COUNT(CASE WHEN (home = @team or away = @team) and (winner <> @team and winner <> "0") then 1 ELSE NULL END) as lost,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN winner = "0" and (home = @team or away = @team) then 1 ELSE NULL END) as tie,
        (869 / 1928) * 100 as win_percent
    from matches
) AS a
```

Comment: Works as intended thank you, will set as answer in 3min.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simplifying your query, using the convenient MySQL extension that treats boolean values as numbers, with `1` for true and `0` for false:

```
SELECT @team team,
       SUM(home = @team) as home,
       SUM(away = @team) as away,
       SUM(@team IN (away, home))) as total,
       SUM(winner = @team and @team IN (away, home)) as win,    
       SUM(winner <> @team and winner <> 0 and @team IN (away, home)) as lost,    
       SUM(winner = '0' and @team IN (away, home)) as tie,
       (869 / 1928) * 100 as win_percent,
       AVG(CASE WHEN @team IN (away, home) THEN winner = @team END) as win_percent
```